# Why does cat with no argument read from standard input?

Tags: history, unix, utilities

In [advice about how to design good CLI commands](https://clig.dev/) I read:

> If your command is expecting to have something piped to it and stdin is an interactive terminal, display help immediately and quit. This means it doesn’t just hang, like `cat`.

This seems like a really good call to me. The default behavior of `cat` is to appear to hang, and to reduplicate anything the user types in an attempt to interact with it. It is such a bad default that I assume it must have been intended for some other context where this behavior would make more sense.

What was that context? Why would I ever want this command to read from standard input? Is there some non-interactive context where this is useful?

I only ever use `cat` to view (short) files in the terminal, but I gather (from the name) that its original purpose was once concatenation of files. What sense does it make to concatenate standard input, with no further argument?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144655/discussion-on-question-by-john-skiles-skinner-why-does-cat-with-no-argument-read); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: I remember there was a utility which emitted an error message like "people don't usually type in their log files on the terminal, but what do I care?" (to standard error, natch) when it sensed that standard input was a terminal. I can't remember which tool it was. Probably some Perl log analyzer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**TL;DR: In UNIX version 1, the easiest way to get unfiltered, human-typed input onto the standard output was with an argument-less `cat`. A few versions later, `echo` would provide another simple means to get human-typed input onto the standard output.**

---

> It is such a bad default that I assume it must have been intended for some other context where this behavior would make more sense.

[`cat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)) was introduced in 1971, UNIX version 1, for the PDP series of minicomputers. Computer I/O at that time used [fancy typewriters called teletypes](https://www.howtogeek.com/727213/what-are-teletypes-and-why-were-they-used-with-computers/) for both input and output<sup>(*)</sup>:

> Popular minicomputers of the late 1960s and early ’70s, such as the PDP-8, PDP-11, and the Data General Nova, supported ASCII encoding, making the Model 33 [teletype] an ideal low-cost (relatively speaking) input/output (I/O) terminal for them. In particular, the PDP series by DEC were influential machines, and if you look up historical photos of them, you’ll almost always see a Teletype Model 33 in use beside them.
> ...
> When you used a teletype with a mainframe [*sic*] computer like these, you’d see your own local input on paper as you typed, and then you’d receive a response from the computer printed below it as the teletype printed to a continuous feed of rolled paper stored within the unit.
> ...
> In 1970, Dennis Ritchie and Ken Thompson developed the UNIX operating system on a PDP-11 using Model 33 teletypes as interfaces, and some of the teletype-related design choices that they made are still with us today.

Where the "bad default" of today made more sense back then was as a way to pass human-typed text to the output teletype, without having to go through a named file -- remember this was *before* McIlroy had conceptualized [pipes](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/304878/129666) and the only way to get data into a named file was to write a program (on tape or hand-entered line by line) that created a named file in the filesystem (there was [no `echo` command](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-1st/1/) until version 6, written by McIlroy no less):

```
cat
--- Here is Today's Weather Report ---
^D
cat report
```

In this example, the user invokes `cat` and types a line of text that acts as a header indicating that the day's weather report is coming, ending that input with an end-of-file sequence. Then the user invokes `cat` again to output a file called `report`.

Of course, the commands the user types will appear on their own console (*de facto* because a teletype is just an ink-on-paper typewriter), but importantly the output of these `cat` commands will go to standard out, which may be [a different teletype](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-1st/1/tty) than the one on which the commands are entered.

For example, in [this picture](https://www.computer-history.info/Page4.dir/pages/PDP.1.dir/) the console teletype giving the commands (middle of photo) is routing output to the large line printer (left of photo):

[image: > Cecelia Larsen [is] sitting at the console typewriter and Bob Kuhn [is] sitting at the CRT. I do not recall the name of the person standing at the Analex line printer.]

In this [picture](https://web.archive.org/web/20230115053547/http://www.columbia.edu/cu/computinghistory/ssio.html), we see the Self Service I/O Area at Columbia University, circa early 1980. Notice that this multi-user environment was also multi-room, with input terminals a good distance away from output terminals.

[image: The Columbia University Self Service Input/Output Area, circa early 1980s.]

The uniformity of treating all devices as files combined with the elegance of all programs having standard input and output channels, allowed UNIX to adapt to many environments and configurations without having to reprogram for every scenario. As reprogramming was expensive and specialized, only the most versatile programs endured: `cat`, now more than 50 years old and unchanged in its essential operation, is proof.

---

In search of direct, authoritative historical evidence, I turned to my copy of [*"UNIX: A History and Memoir"* by Brian Kernighan](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1695978552). I can find no explicit statement that the interactive console for standard input was an explicit design choice, but there are a few choice paragraphs on this subject.

> It’s interesting to speculate about how differently things might have  turned out if Unix had been developed in a world with punch cards instead of  Teletypes.
> -- Kernighan, Brian. UNIX: A History and a Memoir (p. 182). Kindle Edition.

[image: Ken (seated) and Dennis at the PDP-11, ~1972 (Wikipedia)]

> Ken is typing at a Model 33 Teletype, a sturdy but slow and noisy device,  basically a computer-controlled electro-mechanical typewriter that could only  print in upper case, at 10 characters per second. The Model 33 dates from  1963 but earlier versions had been in widespread use since the early 1930s.
> Teletype Corporation was a part of AT&T, and Teletypes were widely used  throughout the Bell System and elsewhere for sending messages, and later for  connecting to computers. Whatever was typed on the Teletype keyboard was  sent to the computer, and responses were printed (in upper case) on a long  roll of paper; the tops of the paper rolls are just visible in the picture.  Arguably, one reason why many command names on Unix are short is that it took considerable physical force to type on a Model 33, and printing was slow.
> Someone even built an experimental “portable” Model 33. The keyboard  and printer were shoehorned into a suitcase-like container that in theory  could be carried around, though at 55 pounds (25 kg) you wouldn’t carry it  far. (It had no wheels either.) It was connected to a remote computer  through a dial-up phone connection and a built-in acoustic coupler: plug a  telephone handset into a couple of rubber sockets and the coupler converted  data into sound and back again, rather like a fax machine.
> -- Kernighan, Brian. UNIX: A History and a Memoir (p. 57-58). Kindle Edition.

It's interesting that in 1978, 6 years after `cat` was written, McIlroy summarized "[T]he Unix philosophy, a style of programming, of how to approach a computing task" with this point:

> Expect the output of every program to become the input to another,  as yet unknown, program. Don’t clutter output with extraneous information. Avoid stringently columnar or binary input formats. Don’t insist on interactive input.
> -- Kernighan, Brian. UNIX: A History and a Memoir (p. 183). Kindle Edition.

Perhaps had pipes and shell redirection been a part of UNIX version 1, then a dedicated program like `read` would have been the only way to read bytes from the interactive console and the absence of a standard input stream to a program would have immediately exited.

---

*Addenda*

The [*PDP-1 Input-Output Systems Manual*](https://www.computerhistory.org/pdp-1/_media/pdf/dec.pdp-1.bell.pdp-1_IO_interface_F-25.1960.102630357.pdf) is a great reference for how the PDP series worked at a line level -- signals, bits, and wires -- and provides a

<sup>(*)</sup> Ben Gurley (designer of the PDP-1) had [written a subroutine](https://www.computerhistory.org/pdp-1/f986f5941bf5ae759ae583b8c42df638/) for displaying characters on the PDP-1 *scope* (barely a character display), but (a) that wasn't universally installed and (b) it still treated the display as a teletype.

Comment: I don't quite get it. Why would they need "a way to echo human typed text to the teletype" when a teletype normally allowed you to "see your own local input on paper as you typed"?

Comment: @JohnSkilesSkinner Great question, which I skipped over originally. I've expanded on this point with my recent edit.

Comment: re *a mainframe computer like these*  'These' meaning PDP-8 and PDP-11, uh-huh.  I wonder what 'Benj Edwards' thinks 'mainframe' means.

Comment: @another-dave Try asking him on Twitter; his contact is in the byline. Smells like an editorial oversight to me and no reason to impugn the author or article.

Comment: This makes a *lot of sense* to me. The apparent reduplication of typed input would be actually useful if input and output were often in physically different locations.  Know of anything more I could read about that?

Comment: @JohnSkilesSkinner I've expanded on that topic.

Comment: I have marked this as correct because it's the only argument that makes historical sense to me. Though I learned a lot of cool things about `|` from the other answers, chronologically the pipeline model cannot be the explanation. However, I am still in search of more direct historical documentation that this was the reason for the feature.

Comment: @JohnSkilesSkinner I hunted for some more direct evidence. No jackpot, but at least some more context.

Comment: From a historical point of view, DEC operating systems (and later CP/M) had a command called PIP (Peripheral Interchange Program) which functioned similarly to cat. It took input from one peripheral and sent it to another. Unix generalized this into stdin/stdout/stderr and pipes.

Comment: Interesting that echo is much later than cat.  Did the shell have to mature first, in order to recognize the need for fully scriptable standard input?

Answer (score 43):

This is not specific to `cat`.  It's a general rule in Unix that, if there are no arguments, the program reads from standard input.  This is also true of `grep`, `od`, `sort`, `split`, `uniq`, `wc`, and so on.  This lets you pipe in the input instead of needing a file, but it will take input from the terminal as well.

Pipes were introduced in V3 Unix, but `isatty()` didn't appear until V7 Unix.  I couldn't tell you if the behavior would be any different if `isatty()` had been available back then, but now it's just the way Unix works.

---

As an addendum, it seems that Plan 9 utilities also have this behavior of waiting for input when invoked without arguments, even though it otherwise departs from historical Unix behavior in many ways.  So, I'd have to conclude that the designers of Unix actually would not have changed this if they were making it today, and it all comes down to a difference in opinion about what the "correct" behavior is.

Comment: But when was fstat added?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144839/discussion-on-answer-by-user24811-why-does-cat-with-no-argument-read-from-standa); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 38):

'cat' fits the pipeline model, which says that for a program with one input and one output, it should read from stdin and write to stdout, at least by default in the case that no files are specified.

Rather than asking why cat reads stdin, I'd ask what benefit you'd gain by **not** having it do that.  I don't accept that tailoring a utility command like cat to people who don't know what it does is a good tradeoff.

This is essentially an argument from consistency, but there's also an argument from simplicity.  If you look at the source code for the primeval Unix utilities, they were pretty minimalist. Why write 'isatty' code (assuming you even have such a system call) when cat works fine without it?

Design decisions made 50 years ago might have used different tradeoffs!

To put you in the right frame of mind, I quote from the [1971 Unix Programmer's Manual](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/bellLabs/unix/UNIX_ProgrammersManual_Nov71.pdf) page for 'cat':

> DIAGNOSTICS: none; if a file cannot be found it is ignored.

Postscript: *I gather (from the name) that its original purpose was once concatenation of files.*  Well, sort of. But it demonstrates a certain parsimony of concept that I like.  You don't need separate 'type out this file' and 'append these files to make a new file', as many other systems have, when one tool can be designed to do both jobs, and simply, too.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144840/discussion-on-answer-by-another-dave-why-does-cat-with-no-argument-read-from-sta); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 8):

I’ve frequently used `cat > somefile.txt` to create a file quickly, and most other long-time UNIX users have as well.  It was quicker and more convenient than `vi` over a slow connection, and much more so than a line editor (as long as I didn’t make any typoes).

Comment: This is the answer I was going to give.  `copy con somefile.txt` does the same thing on dos/windows and I've used both for decades.   If you want to add a couple of lines to the end of a '.gitignore', would you rather fire up an editor, navigate to the bottom, type in your two lines, save the file, and exit the editor, or would you just type `cat >> .gitignore`, type in your lines, and hit CTRL+D?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat Ctrl-Z on Windows!

Answer (score 4):

I use `cat` without arguments all the time, for exactly the purpose it accomplishes.

For example, I edit some unrelated file with `joe` editor (put your other favorite editor here, this is mine) and I need to paste some stuff in it which I want to be included **verbatim**.

If I just pasted text I've selected elsewhere (via `shift-ins` in xterm), all kinds of unwanted things would happen (it would auto-wrap text at right margin, it might auto indent stuff after newlines, it might do semantic things with spaces after colons, it might interpret ASCII sequences with codes less than 32 as control characters which would invoke editor commands instead of being preserved in editor window, etc)

If I however say `ctrl-k r !cat` (meaning: "*run program `cat` and read its output into current editor buffer"*), I can then paste anything without worrying, terminate with EOF (via `ctrl-d`) and be safe in knowing data is imported into editor buffer verbatim.

---

Regarding the historical uses, all those tools were made by default to read from `stdin` pipe and write to `stdout` pipe. To produce the warning when `stdin` refers to the terminal, you need to know that -- and `isatty(3)` libc call needed to do that. And I'm not sure if `isatty` was standardized before SUSv3, or even existing before [Version 7](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7). But some historian should check exact dates...

So on the *"Why didn't it throw an error when stdin is a terminal from the beginning"* - because:

- functionality to determine that might not have existed when they were written
- it requires extra code, and extra features do not drop from the sky, but need someone to invest effort and time to implement them
- it is extra work and extra resources just to make tool be less capable and more bloated. Relatedly, in those days, there were no expectations that computer users need to be nannied. In fact, it was expected that user should be given enough rope to hang themselves (or shoot themselves in the foot), especially if that saved on resources.
- after that, it's compatibility. Even if nowadays there are expectations that machines must be made idiot-proof so even users with absolutely no knowledge what they are doing should be protected from themselves; trying to break that compatibility for existing tools (especially ones as popular as `cat(1)`!) is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144841/discussion-on-answer-by-matija-nalis-why-does-cat-with-no-argument-read-from-sta); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

@user24811 already covered the background, so just an addendum -
displaying help and quitting breaks the pipeline model. I do *not* want the remains of a "helpful message" on file after it has been squeezed through my pipeline, awk'ed, digested and all.

`stdin` is perfect the way it is, and your modern funky terminal, after all, is just a file descriptor if viewed from "the other end". Treating it any different would rob it of that very design foundation.

*cat* is just a way to initiate i/o. When 300bd terminals (or, modem lines) were state of the art, the local line editing capabilities of the terminal were so much faster than the tedious redraw routines taking place while you watched the cursor toggle through your line, that cat was quite often used as the input editor of choice for small files.

And of course, [there's an xkcd](https://xkcd.com/378/)...

Comment: Presumably the 'helpful message' would be on stderr, not  stdout - I believe this is why stderr was invented.  Anyone know when stderr (i.e., fd #2) appeared?  I suppose soon after pipes!

Comment: perfectly true, unfortunately there are way too many tools that don't bother differentiating between stderr and stdout, they'll just blurb something ("echo oops") and exit.

Comment: Even if `cat` (or any other program) complained about its stdin being connected a terminal, it would still work when reading input from a pipe.

Comment: By design, a terminal is a file descriptor. There really is no point in complaining about a terminal being used as starting point for a pipe. We did make use of that bak then, and since the invention of cutbuffers, are doing so even more.

Answer (score 3):

There are use-cases where it makes sense.

- Imagine you want to type or cut&paste text and save it to a file, without starting an editor. A simple `cat > file.txt` can run in a terminal and you are free to type or cut&paste stuff in it.
- Imagine you have a shell script which uses `cat` deeply within some function or in some non-trivial logic; maybe it supports especially the use-case of being run with either a file or `STDIN`, and this behaviour (of the script) may be implemented by having a `cat $FILE` step somewhere, with `$FILE` being allowed to be empty. If `cat` were to change behaviour depending on whether `$FILE` is there or not, this would be confusing or rather very error-prone.

But most importantly, without really counting, the majority of the low-level, small Unix'ish CLI tools I use all day, every day, behaves this way. Very few of them, if at all, change their behaviour when started in an interactive shell, at all. Most commands you'd regularly use in a pipeline, be it `cut`, `sort`, `wc`, `sed`, `awk` or whatever it may be, behave exactly like `cat` - they seemingly "hang", waiting for user input, with no prompt and no information that they are doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Unix was designed on systems very different from the Unix systems of today.  On a typical system today, it's possible to have multiple processes running simultaneously, and even when time slicing is required, switching among processes takes a small fraction of a millisecond.  On the systems for which Unix was designed, however, every task switch would take a substantial fraction of a second as current process memory would have to be written out to disk, and memory for the next process would need to be read from disk.  This lead to two design goals which would be nearly relevant today, but were critical in the 1970s:

1. The number of task switches must be minimized.
2. The number of occasions when a program's output would be visibly affected by the receipt of new input from the user must be minimized.

On a system which, when waiting for user input, would generally able to react to it within 100ms, it is very useful to have a user interface which is based around prompts.  If Unix were intended as a single-user system, having it indicate when input is expected, and of what type, would have made things much more convenient and less confusing.  Unix was not, however, a single-user system, and if multiple users simultaneously did something that would take 200ms to complete, that could cause even a simple action that should generate an instant response to take over a second.  If completing a line of input would usually cause an immediate re-prompt, but would sometimes not do anything for a second or two, that would greatly impede users' input to use the system "fluidly".

Many aspects of Unix that are treated as sacred were designed to satisfy constraints that haven't been relevant for decades.  In many cases, it's not really possible to understand why things are as they are without understanding the constraints, but understanding the constraints will make the reasons for things obvious.

Comment: One constraint was that terminal access was often over a 1200 baud modem or even something slower. You did not want any extra output since that took time to display. Hence the lack of any prompt in `ed`.

Comment: @doneal24: Prompts of 1 or 2 bytes would not present any kind of performance issue even at 300 baud if they indicated when the system was ready for more data.  The issue is that while Unix systems that received a line of input would immediately be ready to buffer another line of input, it would take them awhile to get ready to show the next line.

Comment: Would this change if you were on a system that echoed characters as they were typed?

Comment: @doneal24: BTW, I've long thought it unfortunate that ASCII didn't define codes to indicate readiness/unreadiness to receive data which, rather than starting/stopping the tape reader, would raise/lower a visible flag (or, for later units, turn a light on and off), along with a code to ask the far end to report readiness status.  Having a terminal controller send such a code, and having a terminal indicate when it was received, would allow someone who was entering data to receive confirmation that the far end buffer hadn't gotten full.

Comment: @doneal24: At 110 baud, it might be noticeable.  At 300 baud or faster, unless one is continuously typing 30 characters per second, a two-character prompt would increase the time to process a return keystroke from 66ms to 133ms.  Readily observable, but not objectionable.  At 1200 baud or faster, the time would fall to "barely observable".

Comment: @doneal24: At least such behavior wouldn't be a problem on a system that defers echo until the system is actually able to process input, or at least knows what prompt to display.  If Unix had provided a system call that would accept a list of prompts and input line lengths, and have a terminal controller administer the prompts and receive inputs, it  could have offered a smoother UI which would keep users informed of what was happening.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach often used in scripts is variable pipelining, e.g.

```
someTool --args | $filter > "$outfile"
```

here the `filter=cat` allows to save a plaintext file, and a `filter="gzip -9"` allows to compress it well.

Comment: That would still work even if `cat` (or `gzip`) complained about its stdin being connected to a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of use-cases where stdin is a TTY but stdout isn't, as a way to get keyboard or copy/paste input into other things, like `cat >> file`, as other answers mention.  I've also seen `cat > /dev/null` used as a way to get typed text onto the screen to show another human sitting nearby something that involves special characters and syntax which would be hard to describe in words.

If you were going to put training wheels on `cat`, you might consider `if (argc <= 1 && isatty(0) && isatty(1)) { warn(); exit(1); }` (maybe without the `exit` part), with the warning on stderr including the fact that control-C will get out as always.  (Unlike `vi`, the standard means of quitting work just fine.)

Perhaps also check that stdin and stdout are the *same* TTY (same device major/minor), to avoid breaking a complicated redirect that reads keyboard input from one terminal and outputs it in another.  Obviously much simpler to just not do this, especially since `cat` historically didn't.  The worst-case scenario is that someone takes a minute to realize they should hit control-C, so the danger level is pretty low.

---

I have used `cat` with stdin *and* stdout both connected to the terminal to see how control-D works to "submit" a line from line editing on a "cooked" TTY without pressing enter, i.e. when a `read(2)` system call returns. (It's even more useful to use `strace cat > /dev/null` for that, though.)

This is relevant when [messing around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68819810/how-to-properly-read-a-filename-from-stdin-in-linux-assembly-language) with [toy programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65081389/why-is-this-register-value-in-x86-assembly-from-user-input-different-than-expect) in assembly or C that use `read` directly, since `cat` is a known-good program that also just uses `read` without caring about newlines, and makes a `write` system call after every `read` without extra output buffering to some block or buffer size.  (At least the GNU implementation works that way.)  e.g. to demonstrate that it's not fully safe to assume the last character of a `read` is a newline, even with a large buffer size and assuming you're reading from an interactive terminal.

Of course, if `cat` on its own didn't work, I'd just have run `cat -` or `cat /dev/stdin` which I assume would still work perfectly fine; this obscure use-case doesn't need no-args support.  (Or `strace wc`.)